# Asignar valores a un diccionario a partir de dos listas

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Holi, estoy intentando armar un diccionario a partir de dos listas, una con las claves y otra con el valor:

Las claves logro asignarlas bien usando:

```
   for i in nombre_limpio:
    precios[i] = [precio_limpio]
```

Pero no logro encontrar la manera de hacerlo con los valores. Probé:

```
   for i in nombre_limpio:
       precios[i] = [x for x in precio_limpio]

   for i in nombre_limpio:
       precios[i] = [precio_limpio]
       for x in precio_limpio:
           precios[i] = [x]
```

Alguna idea de como resolverlo?

Comment: Las dos listas corresponden uno a uno? Si es el caso, puedes intentar (con la indentación correcta): 
`precios = {}`
`for i in range(len(nombre_limpio)):
 precios[nombre_limpio[i]] = precio_limpio[i]`

Answer (score 3):

En python concretamente, es posible generar un diccionario a partir de un iterable, en donde cada elemento es un iterable de dos elementos (clave, valor).

En resumen, si tenemos un iterable de claves:

```py
claves = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Y otro iterable de valores tales como:

```
valores = [1, 2, 3]
```

Debemos formar un iterable de la forma:

```py
informacion = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Para finalmente poderlo convertir a un diccionario a través de:

```py
d = dict(informacion)
```

Para poder hacer esta conversión de 2 iterables a uno solo, podemos usar la función `zip`. La función zip toma n iterables y retorna un solo iterable, donde la posición 0 es un iterable de los elementos en la posición 0 de los iterables pasados, en caso de que los iterables pasados a zip sean de distintas longitudes, zip creará un iterable tan largo como el iterable con menos elementos.

El proceso completo sería algo como esto:

```py
claves = ['a', 'b', 'c']
valores = [1, 2, 3]

d = dict(zip(claves, valores))
```